# should iOS Instant Messaging App server send APNS(new message) on foreground

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating an instant messaging application. imagine something like skype or yahoo messenger.

Now our server only sends push notification(for new messages) on when the app is on background/multitasked/minimized. But sometimes the server fails to detect that our app is on background, so sometimes it doesn't send push notification even if the app is on background.

Now I'm thinking that our server should just always send push notifications to device even if it is in foreground(so all messages will have a push notif), but we won't show it(the apns) when in foreground. This way, the server won't need to detect if the app is on background or not.

Do you think it's okay, or there will be a sideeffect of always sending apns, you see, if you are chatting whole day on foreground, the client will receive apns but won't show it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by bad effect?

Comment: for example, will apple stop sending me push notifications? eg: you reach 100 or 500 messages a day. Or maybe push notifications received even if I don't show it, drains battery to much. Also what do you think skype or yahoomessenger does, do they always send apns even on foreground but doesnt show it, or they detect if app is on background and send only apns when app is on background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem to send lots of notification without reading it, if the payload is different.

You are not forced to show notifications with an alert when a notification is received in foreground.